# WPF TabControl acceleration keys with WebBrowser control

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, webbrowser-control, tabcontrol, keyboard-shortcuts

I've a WPF TabControl with acceleration keys set - so user can switch to any Tab by hitting A, B, C and D (without pressing Alt!).
Third Tab contains WebBrowser and if user type in the field of this web browser any letter which coincide with Tab's acceleration keys it switches to another Tab instead of typing in the Google search field:
[image]

Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: Have you tried tried `.Focus()` on the web browser control after you switch tabs?

Comment: @AlexanderRyanBaggett. Where to handle this? What event?

Comment: try the UIElement.GotFocus Event on your TabItems

Comment: Can you elaborate? I don't see how it can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an easy solution.
Attach `AccessKeyPressed` hander to all `TabItems` and change `EventArgs` scope there only if we switch from `TabItem` with header "Tab_B".

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem Header="Tab_A" AccessKeyManager.AccessKeyPressed="TabItem_AccessKeyPressed"/>
    <TabItem Header="Tab_B" AccessKeyManager.AccessKeyPressed="TabItem_AccessKeyPressed">
        <WebBrowser Source="http://google.com"  />
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Tab_C" AccessKeyManager.AccessKeyPressed="TabItem_AccessKeyPressed"/>
    <TabItem Header="Tab_D" AccessKeyManager.AccessKeyPressed="TabItem_AccessKeyPressed"/>
</TabControl>
```

Handler:

```
private void TabItem_AccessKeyPressed(object sender, AccessKeyPressedEventArgs e)
{
    var src = ((sender as TabItem)?.Parent as TabControl)?.SelectedItem as TabItem;
    if (src?.Header as string == "Tab_B")
        e.Scope = src;
}
```